# Using Textbox for local notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

I'm trying to make it so a user can type in the text box what they need to be reminded of for a alarm to go off but if they type it in the notification doesn't show that reminder how do i fix this

Comment: and your code so far..??

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup correctly your notification. Here an example with objective-c where I send a notification after 10 second.

```
- (IBAction)createNotification:(id)sender {

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Put Here your reminder text";
    localNotification.category = @"myCategory";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

The alertBody is the text you can customize and can be the text from a textbox or another control. I hope this can help you